# How to prevent a property beeing set on certain profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot

we want to implement a feature for enabling a user to choose a role in the system, by sending the role he/she wishes to have in the login request.

this feature is meant for testing (creating test-users or assigning roles to existing ones is "impossible" in the customers system) and, of course, should never be deployed to a production environment.

I want to deployment of my application to fail if the property `feature.choose-role` is set to `true` AND the `spring active profile` is set to  `production`.

As we are using springs config-server features, i also want to application to completely stop working if the property is set to true at runtime.

My first attempt was to simply create this Config:

```
@Configuration
public class FeatureToggleGuardConfig {

    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "feature.choose-roles", havingValue = "true")
    @Profile("production")
    public Object preventDeploymentOfRoleChoosingFeatureOnProduction() {
        throw new RuntimeException("feature.choose-roles must not be true in production profile!");
    }
}
```

This works if the property is set to true at deployment, but as i understand, will only attempt to refresh the bean if someone actually tries to use it - which will never happen.

Also - i don't think that it would stop the whole application if this just threw a runtime exception when it is used.

in short:

I want to prevent my application to run (or keep running) if at any time, the property `feature.choose-roles` is true and the active profile is "production".

I do not want to alter production code in order to do this ( `if(feature is enables && profile is production)` etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instead of having a your profile drive some sort of blocker, you can have your profile drive a config bean which says whether or not to use the feature. Then, have the nonProd config read from your property, and have the prod config always return false.

Something like:

```
public interface ChooseRolesConfig {

    boolean allowChoosingRoles();
}

@Profile("!production")
public class NonProdChooseRolesConfig implements ChooseRolesConfig {

    @Value("${feature.choose-roles}")
    boolean chooseRoles;

    @Override
    public boolean allowChoosingRoles() {
        return chooseRoles;
    }
}

@Profile("production")
public class ProdChooseRolesConfig implements ChooseRolesConfig {

    @Override
    public boolean allowChoosingRoles() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then just autowire a ChooseRolesConfig object, and call the method, and regardless of what you change feature.choose-roles to using cloud config, it should always be false for prod.

Disclaimer: I blindly wrote this so it might be missing some annotations or something but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: i would prefer to not accept misconfiguration in the first place, instead of working around it by ignoring invalid input, if possible.

Comment: @billdoor you could change the prod config to throw an exception if `@Value("${feature.choose-roles}") boolean chooseRoles;` is set to true if you want